# How to fix the error: "Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'servername' (using password: NO)"

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, hosted

I am trying to implement a login system on my website and therefore I need to connect a php file to a mySQL database. One problem, I keep getting this error:

Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'servername' (using password: NO)

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Or can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I know this question has been asked like a million times already, but none of those answers have worked for me. They all are solutions for a local server and database, where mine is at a webhost so i think this works different.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$dBUsername = "db username";
$dBPassword = "db passwordd";
$dBName = "db name";
$dBPort = "db port";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dBUsername, $dPassword, $dBName, $dBPort);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Try dropping the port.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a remote database server?

Comment: Did you create password for the username in your remote database server? Where did you host the php file that connects to the database?

Comment: Reference: [Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'name'@'host'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32681786)

Comment: @mario why didn't you hammer it? or you not completely sure?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not exactly sure if that's OPs exact error message. It would usually mean mysql_, not mysqli IIRC.

Comment: @mario Oh I see. Well, theoretically it's the same but slightly different animal. I'll pass on passing it on to "THOR" then ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I already tried dropping the port, didn't do anything.

Comment: @McBern I did create a password for the username in my database. And I host the php file from my webhost. No idea if you meant that.

Comment: You're going to have to see what your hosting company gave you for information on this. There isn't much anyone can do for you here, sorry.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner okay. That's also an answer what helps me ; P. I just didn't know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable name you are using in the password parameter slot is not the same as the one you defined above (**$dBPassword** vs **$dPassword**):

```
$dBPassword = "db passwordd";
// ...
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dBUsername, $dPassword, $dBName, $dBPort);
```

In PHP the undefined variable "$dPassword" will be treated as a NULL which is likely why you're getting that "using password: NO" in the returned error.

Comment: Ohw really. I feel so dumb right now. Thanks. It works. :P

Comment: @RienKlapwijk, don't be too hard on yourself. We all need a fresh set of eyes from time to time.